# Execute 'N' functions in parallel in python

Tags: python, loops, python-multithreading

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I couldn't find an answer which would help me. 
My question is can we execute two functions in parallel in python where each function has a for loop running and printing some values. For example, I have two functions a() and b() where a() is printing the numbers 1..n (say n=3) and b() is printing the numbers 11..n(say n=13) along with the current time. I expect the output to be like :

```
function a :1 2018-11-02 15:32:58
function b :11 2018-11-02 15:32:58
function a :2 2018-11-02 15:32:59
function b :12 2018-11-02 15:32:59
```

but it currently prints the following :

```
function a :1 2018-11-02 15:32:58
function a :2 2018-11-02 15:32:59
function b :11 2018-11-02 15:33:00
function b :12 2018-11-02 15:33:01
```

Code:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import datetime
def a():
    for i in range(1,3):
        print 'function a :'+str(i) + ' ' + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        time.sleep(1)
def b():
    for i in range(11,13):
        print 'function b :'+str(i) + ' ' + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    t1=Thread(target=a())
    t2=Thread(target=b())
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have the `target` as `a()` rather than `a` (note the parentheses). What that means is, you are calling the function `a` and then passing the result of that as the `target` to `Thread`. That isn't what you wanted - you want the `target` to be the function `a` itself. So just remove the parentheses when instantiating your `Thread`s like so:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    t1=Thread(target=a)
    t2=Thread(target=b)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```